# Android: Listview issue-images are wrongly assigned

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i searched SO and tried my best but not able to make it work..i have a listview where i am loading with phone contacts with images. below is my code

```
public ProfileAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, List<Profile> listCont,int renderer, String profileType) {
    super(activity, textViewResourceId, listCont);
    this.renderer = renderer;
    this.listCont = listCont;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.profileType = profileType;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    View rowView;
    public TextView textEmailId= null;
    public TextView textContNo= null;
    public TextView text= null;
    public ImageView photo= null;
    public int position;
}

@Override 
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    //View view = convertView; 
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) { 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext() 
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(renderer, null); 
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name); 
        holder.textContNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactno); 
        holder.textEmailId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.emailId);  
        holder.photo = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);  
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();       
        holder.position = position;
        Profile contact = listCont.get(position); 
        holder.text.setText(contact.getName()); 
        ImageView photo = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);   
        photo.setTag(contact.getMobileNo()); 
        photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.stub_image);
        new LoadImage(photo).execute(contact.getMobileNo()); 
    } 
    return convertView;    
}

class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{ 
    // private final WeakReference<ImageView> viewReference;
    private ImageView img; 

    public LoadImage(ImageView img) { 
        //viewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>( view );
        this.img=img;
    } 

    @Override 
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(final String... params) { 
        new QuickContactHelper(activity, img, (String) params[0]).addThumbnail(); 
        return null;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

the problem is, i am getting the list , but images are loading when i start the scroll, only after scrolling the images are stable and in right position..not sure where iam doing wrong, i want the images should be loaded after list loads and images should be in right position...Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not doing anything if convertView == null. You need to assign the picture both in the if and the else.

```
if (convertView == null) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) (getContext() 
.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)); 
    convertView = inflater.inflate(renderer, null); 

    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    holder.textContNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactno); 
    holder.textEmailId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.emailId);  
    holder.photo = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);  

    convertView.setTag(holder);
}else {
    holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();       
}

holder.position = position;
Profile contact = listCont.get(position); 
holder.text.setText(contact.getName()); 

ImageView photo = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);   
photo.setTag(contact.getMobileNo()); 
photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.stub_image);
```

new LoadImage(photo).execute(contact.getMobileNo());

Comment: can u elaborate your answer...you mean the assigning blank image or original contacts image...?

Comment: No, just do something. Your code in the if-statement needs to assign something. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> You set your image  in adapter inflator so when you scroll adapter
>   modified at runtime. you should image set in activity

Comment: i am confused , can u explain more plzz

Comment: new LoadImage(photo).execute(contact.getMobileNo()); exectue this on activity class and then get image and set them..

Comment: iam doing all this loading  in profile adapter class, how to call this in activity/

Answer (score 0):

You only start AsynckTask when convertview!=null.

To fix this just place all this code outside the if statement:

```
   holder.position = position;
   Profile contact = listCont.get(position); 
   holder.text.setText(contact.getName()); 

   ImageView photo = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge1);   
   photo.setTag(contact.getMobileNo()); 
   photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.stub_image);
   new LoadImage(photo).execute(contact.getMobileNo());
```

For image loading I highly recommend this library:

[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Hope this helps you.